# Azure APIM sleep or delay policy

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management, policies, apim

is there a *sleep policy* or any alternative in **azure apim** so that i can delay for 5 seconds to particular response?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEz2k.png)
In the attached image i need to give 5 seconds of delay or sleep condition to the highlighted condition.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the retry policy to emulate a delay:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#Retry

```
<retry condition="@(true)" count="1" interval="5" />
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible with APIM alone. You could make a call to another endpoint using send-request, that would delay APIM's response, but you have to have such endpoint first.

Answer (score 0):

There's no in built policy which supports delay. Still as a work around following policy can be included.

Following policy sets a variable after 500 milliseconds.

```
            <set-variable name="delayExpression" value="@{
                var curr = System.DateTime.UtcNow.AddMilliseconds(500);
                while(System.DateTime.UtcNow < curr){
                    continue;
                }
                return System.DateTime.UtcNow;
            }"/>
```